# Python Interpolation manually

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to do a linear interpolation of my data as `np.interp()` does but the machine I am using does not have numpy or scipy (and I don't have the rights to install them).
Does anyone know a way to manually code this interp function please?

My idea is to give as an input: x and y and interp_points:

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
y=[0,2,4,6,8,10]

interp_points=[0.5,3.5]
```

And to have as output:

```
[1,7]
```

Here is what I have written for now.
It works but I think there might be a better way to find my left and right boundaries for my points.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
interp_points=[0.5,3.5]
result=[]
for element in interp_points:
    left=0
    right=len(x)-1
    while element>x[left]:
        left+=1
    while element<x[right]:
        right-=1
    if left==right:
        result.append(y[left])
    else:
        result.append(y[left-1]+((element-x[left-1])*(y[right+1]-y[left-1]))/(x[right+1]-x[left-1]))
print(result)
```

Comment: "Does anyone know a way to manually code this interp function please?" - I guess some people know this. There are hundreds of active users on Stack Overflow, so surely _somebody_ knows how to do this. Is this all you wanted to ask?

Comment: I actually wanted to know if that someone in particular could give me an esthetic way of coding this

Comment: I literally tried to answer your question - no sarcasm intended. If you want someone to write code for you, we don't do this here. If you're experiencing issues with your implementation of `np.interp`, please describe them and provide a [mcve]

Comment: My bad then, I have edited my post to add some info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go through the x coordinates to find a pair so xprevious < xsearched < xcurrent, and also walk through the y coordinates at the same time, `zip()` can do that for you. Then interpolate inside the located line segment, and done.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0,2,4,6,8,10]

def thing(xs,ys,x0):
  for x,y in zip(xs,ys):
    if x==x0:       # <- exact "hit"
      return y
    if x>x0:        # px<x0<x - assuming there was a px already
      return py+(y-py)*(x0-px)/(x-px)
    px=x
    py=y

for test in [0.5,3.5]:
  print(thing(x,y,test))
```

This code will gladly die if the xsearched is not between the first and the last coordinates provided.

Answer (score 1):

Find the closest number below the number you are looking for, and the closest number above:

```
p = 1.5
x1 = max([i for i in x if i < p])
x2 = min([i for i in x if i > p])
```

Find the indexes of these locations:

```
x1_i = [i for i in range(len(x)) if i == x1][0]
x2_i = [i for i in range(len(x)) if i == x2][0]
```

Find the corresponding y values:

```
y1 = y[x1_i]
y2 = y[x2_i]
```

Use the linear inteprolation formula to calculate the answer:

```
y_interp = y1 + (p-x1)*((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
```

wrap it up in a function:

```
def interp1d(x, y, p):
    x1 = max([i for i in x if i < p])
    x2 = min([i for i in x if i > p])
    x1_i = [i for i in range(len(x)) if i == x1][0]
    x2_i = [i for i in range(len(x)) if i == x2][0]
    y1 = y[x1_i]
    y2 = y[x2_i]
    y_interp = y1 + (p-x1)*((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
    return y_interp
```

Test it:

```
interp1d(x, y, 1.5)
Out: 3.0
```

Now you can apply it as list comprehension:

```
[interp1d(x, y, i) for i in interp_points]
Out: [1.0, 7.0]
```

You may want to add some more error checking but works in general and doesnt need external libraries.

Comment: Thank you, I think I might need to add a verifior to check whether i is already in x or not but this should do the trick!

Comment: No worries! Its fun to implement your own versions of stuff sometimes